# triggeredAutocomplete search event

Tags: jquery, events

i've a problem with triggeredAutocomplete script that i've found in this page:
http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/9391/

I've written this script:

```
$(function() {
    $("#eAd_Post_Home").triggeredAutocomplete({
        source: "add_user.php",
        search: function(event, ui) {$('#tri_autocomplete_div ul').empty();},
        trigger: "@" 
    })
    .data("triggeredAutocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {

        return $("<li class='autocomplete_li'></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append(item.id)
        .appendTo($('#tri_autocomplete_div ul'));
    };
    $("#eAd_Post_Home").triggeredAutocomplete({
        close: function(event, ui) {$('#tri_autocomplete_div ul').empty();$("#tri_autocomplete_div").css("display", "none");}
    });
});
```

But the search event to delete the suggestion doesn't work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the [`appendTo` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo) to have the autocomplete widget handle that for you.

Then you can try this code:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#eAd_Post_Home").triggeredAutocomplete({
        source: "add_user.php",
        search: function(event, ui) {
            $('.ui-autocomplete').empty();
        },
        close: function(event, ui) {
            $('.ui-autocomplete').empty();
            $("#tri_autocomplete_div").hide();
        },
        appendTo: '#tri_autocomplete_div',
        trigger: "@"
    })
    .data("triggeredAutocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li class='autocomplete_li'></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append( item.id )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```